# Is there anything wrong with returning the same object that the method accepts?

Tags: c#, oop

I have a method called **SubmitRequest** wich takes a request object. It fills in some additional values like the sequence id the DB generates and submitted date. Then returns the same object. Is it better to just leave it as a VOID method?

```
Request request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request >(jsonFormData);

RequestManager frMan = new RequestManager();
//frMan.SubmitRequest updates the request object by updating some of its properties.
request = frMan.SubmitRequest(request);

return request;
```

A void would still work as the request would be modified:

```
frMan.SubmitRequest(request);
```

**but are there any advantages or disadvantages of these two ways?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no harm in writing it that way. In fact, it's the basis of a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Comment: However, the `Submit` method here is confusing from a fluent perspective since it's not clear whether it returns the request or the request manager. One could equally expect to be able to write `frmMan.Submit(request1).Submit(request2)` (submit two requests) or `frmMan.Submit(request).Disconnect()` (submit a request and immediately disconnect the manager).

Answer (score 2):

I would say the important thing here is not to make your code confusing.

I would either return the same object...

```
public Request SubmitRequest(Request request)
```

or use a ref parameter to indicate your intentions...

```
public void SubmitRequest(ref Request request)
```

or I guess you could just document your method fully so it is clear and do...

```
/// <summary>
/// This function will modify your request data!
/// </summary>
/// <param name="request">The request data to be submitted</param>
public void SubmitRequest(Request request)
```

Comment: The `ref` parameter is quite unusual and probably not what you intend. Assuming the `Request` is a reference type it is passed by reference to the method. Using the `ref` allows the `SubmitRequest` method to update the _variable_ containing the reference of the calling method. You almost never want to do that and certainly not in this example.

Comment: @MartinLiversage, yes I see what you mean.. my intentions where to make it obvious that the method would be modifying the input - but I understand your point

Comment: I was going to go this route (#2).. why can't i use ref? I am updating the value of request by updating some of it's properties.

Comment: @capdragon, I think the point is that you are essentially referencing a reference and it just does not need to be done. I imagine it will work fine, but I have never really tried it. I use ref very little to be honest

Comment: @capdragon: If you change the signature to `SubmitRequest(ref Request request)` you will be able reassign the `request` variable defined in the calling method to a new value from within `SubmitRequest`. I don't think you want to do that. In general avoid `ref` parameters unless you _really_ need it for some obscure reason.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment back into `request` suggests that `SubmitRequest` can return something different, say, it returns a new request that is somehow related to the submitted one.

Typically, the case where you see this "return the object back" pattern is a `return this` to permit method chaining.

```
var result = request.SubmitTo(frMan).WaitForResult().GetResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you need to think about what's happening here.

Just looking at the code, I would assume that this is what's happening:

1) frMan submits the passed in request
2) frMan returns a new request

Which is not the steps that you've described in the text of the question.

Since you're manipulating the Request object, and then (presumably doing something with it later) I would have the request object be passed to the method BY REFERENCE and return void.  That way  I know that I'm only dealing with one Request object, and that it's the same one.  Additionally, I would provide "SubmitRequest" with a more logically defined name that describes what you're doing to the request object.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's fine as part of something like the builder pattern (see `StringBuilder.Append` for example). However:

- It's not really clear to me that *in this case* it's a good idea.
- You should explicitly document that this is exactly how the method behaves, and that it will never return a *different* reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to do anything with the modified object then I wouldn't return it in the method call.

Thinking about this in the Command/Query paradigm, `SubmitRequest` looks more like a command than a query in which case it makese sense not to return a value.

Comment: Well i do want to return the request to the user with the updated submitted date and add it to a grid and what not. (updated my question to reflect the return request).

Answer (score 0):

It is better to leave it as a void method.

The idea of returning an object is so when something changes, but if nothing changes at all. Then data isn't being manipulated so theres no point of using a return

ex:

```
Object bar = new Object();

// this doesn't do anything. (it wont change the local scope of the object value)
foo(bar); // can be same as void.

//changes the value, but the method returns the same object... whats the point?
bar = foo(bar);

public Object foo(object bar)
{
return bar;    
}
```

Although theoretically, it won't do any harm.

Comment: Have you ever used StringBuilder or any other builder pattern, where it's *common* to return a reference to the same object for the purposes of method chaining?

Comment: but i do make changes "It fills in some additional values like the sequence id the DB generates and submitted date"

Comment: unless you are going to do any other changes or use that object its better to keep it as void. otherwise return the object.

Answer (score 0):

The caller of the method has no guarantee that the instance you return is the same one they provide. When you return `void`, you are explicitly stating that the caller can be sure they are dealing with the same instance after the call completes.

Answer (score 0):

In returning an object, in the following manner:

```
private SomeObject DoSomeStuff(SomeObject item)
{
  // perform work on item and change values

  return item;
}
```

instead of

```
private SomeObject DoSomeStuff( ref SomeObject item)
{
  //perform work on item
}
```

As I understand it you'll incur a slight performance hit as a new object of type `SomeObject` will be created and returned, leaving the garbage collector to tidy up the original object.

As already pointed out if you were to perform any instance checking then this would also fail.

Answer (score 0):

If the point of

```
frMan.SubmitRequest(request);
```

is to update the Request argument, then shouldn't this be a property of the Request object not the RequesManager? Something like

```
request.Submit();
```

?

Comment: You bring up a good point but the RequestManager is in the Data Access Layer and the Request object is in the Business Layer. (Two seperate DLLs). So i would love to do what you say but wouldn't that be wrong to mix the Business Layer and the Data layer?